# How to seperate multi-digit integer in list of list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have this input:

```
12 13 23 31 34 41
```

From here, I want to have a list of list of ints:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 4], [4, 1]]
```

This is my code so far

```
e1 = (input())
e1 = e1.split()
def nest_lists(lst):
    return [[el] for el in lst]
edges = nest_lists(e1)
for i in range(len(edges)):
    for x in range(len(edges[i])):
        edges[i][x] = int(edges[i][x])

print(edges)
```

My output currently is:

```
[[12], [13], [23], [31], [34], [41]]
```

Comment: a list of lists on integers? Do you mean a hash table?

Comment: I think you meant the output should be `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 4], [4, 1]]` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace I edited the problem for clarity, yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `input` I assume your actual input is the string `'12 13 23 31 34 41'`.

You can use a combination of `split`, `list` and `map` to get this done in a some what functional manner:

```
e1 = '12 13 23 31 34 41'
output = list(map(lambda x: list(map(int, list(x))), e1.split()))
print(output)
```

outputs

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 4], [4, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is perfectly good, but since you tagged the question with `list-comprehension` I thought you might also like to see this:

```
text_in = '12 13 23 31 34 41'
text_out = [
    [int(character) for character in word]
    for word in text_in.split(" ")
]
print(text_out)
```

similarly results in:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 4], [4, 1]]
```